# CakePHP get a generic reference to the Model from inside the Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, model

(CakePHP 2.3, CentOS) So, here's the deal: I have a controller 'SpecialController' I've written which does some handy acrobatics that I need in my application. To do its job it needs to know about the Model object. The model in this case is $this->User. The SpecialController has no way of knowing about this because it's just a base class, so I tell it about the Model explicitly inside beforeFilter():

```
class UsersController extends SpecialController {

    function beforeFilter() {

    $this->bindModel($this->User);

    parent::beforeFilter();

    }
```

The bindModel() function just records a reference internally so that my SpecialController can do special things. I want to get out of having to tell it about $this->User. Is there a property which has a reference to the Model? I suspect that there's something like "$this->modelObj" which gets set to the same value as "$this->User", but I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the controller as base class you could do something like this:

```
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->bindModel($this->{$this->modelClass});
    // or 
    $this->bindModel(ClassRegistry::init($this->modelClass));
}
```

Not sure if that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

see this in the cake book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses

Comment: That gives the name of the Model, but I can't grab the object dynamically with ReflectionClass because apparently the model reference $this->User is not a public property. Back to square one. Thanks anyways!

Comment: this seem like a class that needs to go into the Lib folder